# Flask/uWSGI - too many processes after some time

Tags: python-3.x, flask, uwsgi

All, I'm developing a flask-based API using uWSGI v2) as the app server (w/ NGINX, if relevant). The uWSGI .ini file is:

```
[uwsgi]
module = WSGI
callable = app
master = true
processes = 5
socket = /var/uwsgi/api.sock
uid = gg_python
gid = www-data
vacuum = true
venv = /home/gg_python/flask_projects/api/apivenv3
die-on-term = true
daemonize = /tmp/uwsgi_daemonize.log
```

**Update:** here's the uWSGI startup summary output:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.10 (64bit) on [Fri Jun 26 08:31:52 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.9.2 on 29 April 2015 17:23:06
os: Linux-3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt9-3~deb8u1 (2015-04-24)
nodename: debian-api
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /home/gg_python/flask_projects
detected binary path: /home/gg_python/flask_projects/api/apivenv3/bin/uwsgi
your processes number limit is 7972
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 65536
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/uwsgi/api.sock fd 3
Python version: 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:47:48)  [GCC 4.9.1]
PEP 405 virtualenv detected: /home/gg_python/flask_projects/api/apivenv3
Set PythonHome to /home/gg_python/flask_projects/api/apivenv3
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x19faca0
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 436608 bytes (426 KB) for 5 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x19faca0 pid: 20775 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
```

After a while (about 1 day from uWSGI's startup is enough to see effect), I'm getting dozens of open processes. htop screenshot (a few hours after a reload):

[image: htop output uwsgi/flask]

This gets much longer after a day. Of course, API becomes less responsive. 
How can I debug this? Any way to see what's keeping all these processes and sub-processes open? Note that the API isn't really that busy. I'm really the only one using it for now and it rarely has any significant load, and never anything close to requiring dozens of processes.

Any ideas on how to debug this process inflation issue?

Comment: This is a uWSGI configuration issue. Do you have threads enabled, what's your forking mode etc. (Didn't go through the config in detail)

Comment: Threads are disabled, preforking mode. Added startup summary to question.

Comment: @FreekWiekmeijer, thanks, your inquiry pushed me in the right direction. Apparently, it was the enable-threads issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone sees this issue with a similar setup, the problem was threads where disabled. uWSGI indicates this at startup (see question body):

```
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
```

add command line parameter `--enable-threads` or add the following to the uWSGU .ini initialization file: `enable-threads=true`

I did use the threading module in the code and uWSGI does not spawn more processes once threads were enabled.